# Child styled-component not being provided with correct theme during test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, enzyme, styled-components

I'm trying to write a that will `mount(<MyComponent />)` but I'm having trouble with `styled-components` that are rendered by `MyComponent`

Child component

```
const Layout = styled.View`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.background.main};
`
```

Tested component

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <Modal visible>
    <Layout>
      ...
    </Layout>
  </Modal>
)
```

My test

```
const theme = {
  background: {
    main: '#fff',
  },
}

it ('should mount', () => {
  mount(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
})
```

When I run this test I get an error `Cannot read property 'main' of undefined`

I tried to console log the `theme` prop from the `Layout` component and it confirmed that the provided theme prop is an empty object and not the theme from the theme provider. Is there any way I can `mount` using the provided theme?

I also tried using the component wrapper but the result stayed same

```
mount(<MyComponent />, {
  wrappingComponent: ThemeProvider,
  wrappingComponentProps: {
    theme,
  },
})
```

Package versions: `styled-components` are 4.3.2, `enzyme` is `3.10.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I was able to get this test to work using `react-test-renderer` instead of `enzyme`

Helper function

```
const renderWithTheme = (component: JSX.Element) =>
    renderer.create(<ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>{component}</ThemeProvider>)
```

Test:

```
it('renders', () => {
    const component = renderWithTheme(
        <InputModal open={true} value={'abc'} onEditing={mockEditing} title="Test" onEndEditing={mockEndEditing} />,
    )
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a little error. Look at your `theme` object on your test.

It has the property `backgroundColor` but in your code you use the property `theme.background`

Comment: Good catch, unfortunately that doesn't fix my problem :( I had it correct in my project, just wrote it wrong here... I updated my post

Comment: Change your code a little bit:

`const Layout = styled.View\`
  background-color: ${({ props }) => props.theme.background.main};\`
`

Comment: The ThemeProvider injects a new `theme` prop to your component. Try using like that

Comment: I'm trying to use `ThemeProvider` like that. The problem is that it doesn't work with child components which should use `Context` to get the theme but that doesn't work in `Enzyme`. When using the app this components works as expected

Comment: Which SC version are you using ?

Comment: `styled-components` are 4.3.2, `enzyme` is `3.10.0`

Comment: Try the following, please. 
At your component import the `withTheme` HoC from `styled-components` package. Like `import styled, { withTheme } from "styled-components"`

At your export statement, wrap your component with the HoC function like this: export default withTheme(MyComponent)

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately the result is still the same

Comment: When you use like that you have to access the theme as a prop. like prop.theme

Comment: Yes, with this I get passed correct theme as a prop in `MyComponent`. But in the `Layout` `props.theme` is still empty object `{}`

Comment: so, instead of using the `withTheme` on your MyComponent use it on Layout component

Comment: But I found that is a real issue of SC. Take a look here:
https://spectrum.chat/styled-components/jest/i-cant-mount-with-context-after-upgrading-to-react-16-6-and-styled-components-v4~42a60ef4-5c16-4571-b2a5-abb7fffe4013